# Google Apps Script with Query Strings

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

When using `UrlFetch.fetch(url)` it appears to strip querystrings. For instance asking for:

http://www.locksmiths.co.uk/?sm-xml-search=1

the result which is returned is for:

http://www.locksmiths.co.uk/

instead.

Is it possible to use `UrlFetch.fetch(url)` for addresses requiring querystrings or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use them. Yours looks badly formatted. Why do you have the '?' After '/'. Usually you do site.com/x/y?param=z

Comment: Their URL scheme has a trailing slash. Having tried with both URL's I keep getting the result for `http://www.locksmiths.co.uk/` when querying `http://www.locksmiths.co.uk/?sm-xml-search=1`.

Comment: try on other url without the / to determine if thats the problem. never seen a scheme like that.

Comment: As stated I have tried with both URL's. Filed a bug: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3324&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Comment: have you checked what is being received by your site?

Comment: @DavidF When trying a URL under my control I receive a version without the querystring.